# Easiest way to Implement Scripting to WPF C# Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, scripting, visual-studio-2015

I'd like some help in how to add scripting support to a WPF C# project I'm doing on Visual Studio 2015. One of the things I'd like to do is to be able to change User Control properties within that script. I've being trying Roslyn C#, and I read some stuff about IronPython and PowerShell Tools. But, all that information is not really helping.

So, do you have a simple answer? Like, the easiest way to execute scripts in Visual Studio 2015 C# WPF Application, that are able to change properties of User Controls within the project?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Lucas.

Answer (score 0):

[T4 templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) can help but they are less extensible than lets say Roslyn.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great post on how to easily implement IronPython and how to access User Controls within the scripts in Python, so you can there change different Control properties, and even create them! Here's the link:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/602112/Scripting-NET-Applications-with-IronPython

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be quite simple to embed powershell or F# interactive in an application and there are lots of examples when we search the web for this.  The question is only are we comfortable writing scripts in Powershell and F#?

In my application I provide a C# editor and compile *scripts* as static methods (which I uses as functions) using the standard .Net compiler API's which are installed with the framework (Microsoft.Csharp, System.CodeDom).  This generates a temporary dll and perhaps can not be properly termed a script.  The implementation is straight forward and more or less what you expect - I have to provide a way for the users to specify references and namespaces, then generate a source file, compile it to an assembly and then call members of the static class.  This above technique works well because the application has extension points that are well adapted to user defined code with a certain well defined structure (you might have similar well defined needs and perhaps full scripting is not necessary).

On the other hand, I am considering providing a "super user" console where the application can be driven by script, and in this case, I will use either Powershell or F-sharp interactive (I'm leaning towards F#).  I don't think the implementation is particularly complex, but these are things that can easily bring the application down or corrupt application data if it is not well controlled - and it is unlikely that my users will profit from scripting as it is a *programmer* environment.